# How to center text vertically in a flex box?

Tags: css, centering, flexbox

Just found the solution to my problem as I was going to ask it here.

So I thought I could share this with you.

I needed to distribute verticaly three items, with centered content.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <a id="item1">Item 1</a>
    <a id="item2">Item 2</a>
    <a id="item3">Item 3</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
#container a{
    flex:1;
}
#container a:nth-child(odd){
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.2); /* Just for visibility purpose */
}
```

With this code, a flex context is create to distribute the `a` tags among the available vertical space. However, I was wondering how to get their text centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the idea is to turn each sub-item as a flexbox. Then, we'll be able to easily center their content.

NEW CSS:

```
#container{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    /* text-align:center; <-- This is now unappropriate */
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}
#container a{
    flex:1;

    /* This was added:      */
        display:flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
}
```